# Remove disabled menu links from menu settings

Tags: routes, hooks, forms, navigation

I have a multilingual site, and when adding content theres an option to add a menu link. Both languages show up in the drop down selection, my goal is to hide/remove the links that are "disabled" (NOT in the current language).

So only the current language links should be visible in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never solved this, finally i deleted the drupal site and rewrote the site with dogescript.